# Checking for variable value using Checkstyle/PMD/Findbugs

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I have a multi-modules Maven project currently running Checkstyle, PMD and Findbugs. In certain classes I have methods with annotations. These annotations have a parameter with a value that needs to follow a certain regex. Is there an easy way to look for this parameter value and verify if it follows the pattern using any of the previously mentioned tools. I have tried writing a custom check for Checkstyle. However, since Checkstyle only sees line by line, it cannot verify parameters that are set using final strings. I have looked around but couldn't find anything. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. This looks like a prime case for PMD's [XPath rules](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.5.0/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_xpath_rules.html#using-designer).

You can write an XPath expression over the AST to match annotations that don't comply to your definition. Also, [the designer](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.5.0/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_xpath_rules.html#using-designer) is very useful to help you develop and test your rule.

So you could probably write something such as:

```
//Annotation[pmd-java:typeIs('java.lang.SuppressWarnings') and .//MemberValue//Literal[not(matches(@Image, '[0-9]+'))]]
```

Will match all `@SuppressWarnings` annotations, that have a value not matching `[0-9]+`. You can further refine this to look for values of a specific key if needed.

Once you are ok with your XPath, you simply write it [into your ruleset](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.5.0/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_xpath_rules.html#creating-a-new-rule-definition) and can start running it on your codebase.

Notice the XPath given in the example is an XPath 2.0, as it uses the `matches` function not available in older versions. PMD supports XPath 1.0, 1.0 compat mode and 2.0, being 1.0 the default, but overridable in the rule definition

Comment: The type of the Name is rolled up to the annotation so no need to fetch the Name node ;)

Comment: @LFarquaad glad to help! Remember to mark the answer as correct for future reference.